# Sorting alphanumeric string in Kotlin (numeric, not lexicographical order)

Tags: kotlin, natural-sort

I was trying to sort this list

```
val list = mutableListOf("1", "2", "10", "A10", "A1", "A2","B24C","A")
list.sort()
println(list)
```

It gives [1, 10, 2, A, A1, A10, A2, B24C],
but what I want is [1, 2, 10, A, A1, A2, A10, B24C]

This order I want is 0-9 ascending, then A-Z ascending, like 1,2,3,A1,A2,B1,B2,etc

Comment: Why should "A" come between "2" and "10"?

Comment: Can you describe the order you want, and/or what it's for?  That might help us understand the underlying requirement.  (And it would be well worth documenting in your code's comments, so whoever maintains it can understand it too.)

Answer (score 1):

What I found was if I use sort() on String, it will do a lexicographic sort. If I want a numeric kind of sort, I can do:

```
list.sortBy { it.toInt(Character.MAX_RADIX) }
```

source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/118bvui/comment/j9ib8q4